# Retrieving sessions using getCurrentSession() and openSession() in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I have a little confusion in retrieving sessions using getCurrentSession() and openSession(), many articles mentioned that getCurrentSession creates a brand new session if one is not already existing and does not create a new session if a session is already available, and on the other hand openSession creates a brand new session.

1. Here I have a confusion does openSession() always creates a brand new session?
2. Does hibernate pools sessions to uses the same session in the getCurrentSession()?

Can you please help me to clarify this and apologies for any mistake I made

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Yes.**
   `openSession()` binds the session to the current context. Default context is `Thread`, it can also be bound on `HttpRequest` level using custom filter or [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)
2. **No.** Hibernate does not have actual connection pool out the box. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880577/hibernate-what-is-the-connection-pool-and-why-is-the-default-one-unsuitable-for). A session is opened whenever `getCurrentSession()` is called for the first time in that particular context. after that to find already existing session Hibernate uses [`CurrentSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext.html) to determine current context and will return session bound to that particular context. Majority of Application Servers associates a session with a `Thread` which is created using the underlying `ThreadLocal` object.