# Hibernate NESTED EXCEPTION

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a problem with hibernate NESTED EXCEPTION. Couple of hours after deploying the app on server, these errors start showing up. I think the problem is with mysql connection which expires. Tomcat 7, show me that application has memory leaks too.

Sample dao class(sometimes app have orm query, sometimes sqlquery)

```
    public List<Object[]> getPckey(String labId){

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try{
    sessionFactory = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    String asd = "SELECT pcKey, regDate, pcKeyStatus, unRegDate FROM PcKey WHERE idLaboratory = :laboratoryId AND pcKey IS NOT NULL ORDER BY pcKeyStatus DESC, unRegDate";
    Query query = session.createQuery(asd);
    query.setParameter("laboratoryId", labId);
    List<Object[]> results = query.list();

    tx.commit();
    return results;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

HibernateAnnotationUtil class

```
public class HibernateAnnotationUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml");
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Stacktrace

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: Connection reset STACKTRACE: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1960)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2874)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1403)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
at com.want.ecdlejb.dao.CheckIsPcExistDao.isPcExist(CheckIsPcExistDao.java:32)
at com.want.ecdlejb.services.CheckIsPcExistService.isPcExist(CheckIsPcExistService.java:18)
at com.want.ecdlwar.computers.CheckIsPcExist.isPcExist(CheckIsPcExist.java:17)
at com.want.ecdlwar.rest.server.Rest.checkIsPcExist(Rest.java:139)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: To prevent DB connection timeout errors, use Hibernate pooling (like c3p0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) Connection Pool

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>

  . . . .
</session-factory>
```

OR use Apache [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) Connection Pool

For details about Connection Pooling you can read this [Hibernate: What is the connection pool and why is the default one unsuitable for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880577/hibernate-what-is-the-connection-pool-and-why-is-the-default-one-unsuitable-for)

Comment: `timeout` value should be greater than the `idle_test_period` value. Otherwise `idle_test_period` property is useless.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful

Answer (score 1):

According to stack trace, your dao is throwing an exception :
at

> com.want.ecdlejb.dao.CheckIsPcExistDao.isPcExist(CheckIsPcExistDao.java:32)

And as is see, in `getPcKey()` method, when exception occurs, you only print stack trace in catch block, you have to rollback your transaction here `tx.rollback()` (in your catch block), otherwise, this will lead to connection leak.
You should also (as suggest below) think to use a connection pool and configure it correctly.

I hope that this could help !
Regards

Comment: Thanks, that was useful

Comment: Great to know ! could you close the question plz ?