# how to get the size of hibernate connection pool?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have an app that is written in java spring.
It uses hibernate to handle connections to postgres DB.
I want to get the size of the connection pool, but it isn't defined on the app's hibernate configurations.
So I guess it uses hibernate default size, which is 1?
That sounds very low to me.
How can I be sure what is the size of connection pool?
I read that it is recommended to use third party manager for this, but I don't think it's in used also.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't manage connection pool, you have to use some this like HikariCP or C3PO or similar library.

Comment: it does, but it isn't recommended to use in production.
i don't find in my app any use of HikariCP or C3PO

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880577/hibernate-what-is-the-connection-pool-and-why-is-the-default-one-unsuitable-for#:~:text=Hibernate%20doesn%27t%20really,mechanism%20by%20default.)

Comment: tnx, but this is not giving me news :/